# Find number of pairs separated pairs of 1s in a string

Tags: python, regex, string, matching

I am trying to count the number of separated pairs of 1s in a string using a regex and `re.findall()` in Python.
The regex applied to the string `11110` should return `2` and applied to `01101` it should return `1`.

My code is the following:

```
matches = len(re.findall(r'1[\w]+1', str1))
```

But applied to `110110` it returns `1` as it is only finding the substring `11011`.  I would expect it to also find the substring `101`.
Is my regex wrong or is `re.findall()` not the function I should be using?

Comment: Try using this regex `11+`. Test your Regex [here](https://regex101.com/) before using it in your code.

Comment: Try 11{2}. 11+ will not work as regex by nature will find longest match.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee There's nothing wrong with the regex. The problem is that `re.findall` does not support overlapping.

Comment: Can you btw explain why it should give only one match on `01101`? You will have both `101` and `1101`.

Comment: Define what you mean by *separated pairs of 1s*? Also: `\w` includes `1` in the range of `0-9` so it not clear what you are looking for.

Comment: Also, for 110110 your description tells me it should be four mathes. **1**10**1**10 **1**101**1**0 1**1**0**1**10 and 1**1**01**1**0.

Comment: Perhaps I should have been clearer.  I need UNIQUE matches after finding a match the 1 that define it shouldn't be reconsidered.  That is why `110110` only matches twice.  Maybe I could use `find` and insert two 0s in place of the 1s after the first match?  But how would I know their exact position?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> Return all **non-overlapping** matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings.

The `re` module does not support overlapping, but `regex` does. Install the `regex` module and do like this:

```
>>> import regex
>>> regex.findall(r'1[\w]+1', '1111001', overlapped=True)
['1111001', '111001', '11001', '1001']
```

Comment: Thank you but I tried `111010` and it is returning `3`, not `2` as I need.  This because it is matching `11101`, `1101` and `101`.  I need the 1s used for a matching not to be reconsidered.  This way `111010` would match only to `11101` and `1101`.